# VirtualEnv creates envs. with all system wide packages instead of clean env

Tags: python, virtualenv

Early on I made the mistake of not using virtualenv and hence I have many packages installed system wide. However now when I create a virtualenv and activate it, if I pip freeze or pip list, it shows all the packages I have installed system wide.

How do I start a clean virtualenv?

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you did to create your env.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `--no-site-packages` option.

**Example:**

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages /some/path
```

**Note:** The very useful [virtualenvwrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper) also accepts most of the same command-line options as [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

Comment: Fast and helpful answer, thanks man! Don't know how I didn't find it myself.